# update query statement in informix

Tags: sql, hibernate, informix

I would to get help from you all regarding my sql statement in `Infomix`.Please find my code below.I'm joining 5 tables and link with the primary keys. what I need is, I have to update export_flag column to Y based on the `export_flag='N'` and `country='MA'`.

But right now i'm hitting a syntax error like this

> 13:34:12  [UPDATE - 0 row(s), 0.000 secs]  [Error Code: -201, SQL
>   State: 42000]  A syntax error has occurred.

I couldn't find where could be the problem in my SQL.

```
    update a set a.export_flag ='Y'
    FROM sc_ob_temp_audit AS a
    JOIN sc_ob_allocation  AS b
    ON a.sc_ob_profile_code = b.sc_ob_profile_code 
    AND a.sc_orig_country= b.sc_orig_country
    OUTER JOIN sc_fac_group AS f 
    ON b.sc_orig_country = f.sc_orig_country 
    AND b.sc_orig_sf_group_code = f.sc_fac_group_code
    OUTER JOIN sc_ob_prod_group AS d, JOIN gbl_produce AS e 
    ON d.sc_prod_cont_code = e.gp_cnt_cd
    AND b.sc_orig_country= d.sc_orig_country
    AND b.sc_prod_cont_group_code = d.sc_prod_group_code
    WHERE a.sc_orig_country ='MY'
    AND a.export_flag='N';
```

Comment: -> OUTER JOIN sc_ob_prod_group AS d, JOIN gbl_produce AS e

Answer (score 3):

Informix does not support that sort of UPDATE with JOINs — see the syntax at the [IBM Informix 11.70 InfoCenter](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/topic/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1254.htm) for UPDATE.  And it gives error -201 when it comes across syntax it doesn't recognize.

---

> If Informix doesn't support update with join then how could join the tables? Anyway I have to convert this query to Hibernate later on.

I want to go into hibernation now, please...You mean, you want me to interpret your query and work out how to do it?  Without the schemas of the tables (primary keys, foreign keys particularly relevant!)?  You'll definitely have to fix it in Hibernate; I've never used it.

Here's your query, reformatted for what seems to me like better readability.

```
UPDATE a
   SET a.export_flag ='Y'
  FROM sc_ob_temp_audit AS a
  JOIN sc_ob_allocation  AS b
    ON a.sc_ob_profile_code = b.sc_ob_profile_code 
   AND a.sc_orig_country= b.sc_orig_country
  LEFT JOIN sc_fac_group AS f 
    ON b.sc_orig_country = f.sc_orig_country 
   AND b.sc_orig_sf_group_code = f.sc_fac_group_code
  LEFT JOIN sc_ob_prod_group AS d   -- ON clause missing (but there was a comma here)
  JOIN gbl_produce AS e 
    ON d.sc_prod_cont_code = e.gp_cnt_cd
   AND b.sc_orig_country= d.sc_orig_country             -- Part of missing ON clause?
   AND b.sc_prod_cont_group_code = d.sc_prod_group_code -- Part of missing ON clause?
 WHERE a.sc_orig_country ='MY'
   AND a.export_flag='N';
```

To my untrained eye, that looks like a vastly complex way of writing:

```
UPDATE sc_ob_temp_audit
   SET export_flag = 'Y'
 WHERE sc_orig_country = 'MY'
   AND export_flag = 'N'
```

However, presumably all the joining does something useful, somehow restricting the set of rows that is updated.  So, we can guess that it means something like:

```
UPDATE sc_ob_temp_audit
   SET export_flag = 'Y'
 WHERE sc_orig_country = 'MY'
   AND export_flag = 'N'
   AND sc_primary_key IN      -- Guessed at column; no schema for the DB; no keys!
       (SELECT a.sc_primary_key
          FROM sc_ob_temp_audit AS a
          JOIN sc_ob_allocation  AS b
            ON a.sc_ob_profile_code = b.sc_ob_profile_code 
           AND a.sc_orig_country    = b.sc_orig_country
          LEFT JOIN sc_fac_group AS f 
            ON b.sc_orig_country       = f.sc_orig_country 
           AND b.sc_orig_sf_group_code = f.sc_fac_group_code
          LEFT JOIN sc_ob_prod_group AS d
            ON b.sc_orig_country         = d.sc_orig_country
           AND b.sc_prod_cont_group_code = d.sc_prod_group_code
          JOIN gbl_produce AS e 
            ON d.sc_prod_cont_code = e.gp_cnt_cd
       )
```

If in fact you don't have a single-column primary key on the `sc_ob_temp_audit` table, you have to use a correlated sub-query with EXISTS instead:

```
UPDATE sc_ob_temp_audit
   SET export_flag = 'Y'
 WHERE sc_orig_country = 'MY'
   AND export_flag = 'N'
   AND EXISTS
       (SELECT *         -- It does not matter what you list here in an EXISTS sub-query
          FROM sc_ob_temp_audit AS a
          JOIN sc_ob_allocation  AS b
            ON a.sc_ob_profile_code = b.sc_ob_profile_code 
           AND a.sc_orig_country    = b.sc_orig_country
          LEFT JOIN sc_fac_group AS f 
            ON b.sc_orig_country       = f.sc_orig_country 
           AND b.sc_orig_sf_group_code = f.sc_fac_group_code
          LEFT JOIN sc_ob_prod_group AS d
            ON b.sc_orig_country         = d.sc_orig_country
           AND b.sc_prod_cont_group_code = d.sc_prod_group_code
          JOIN gbl_produce AS e 
            ON d.sc_prod_cont_code = e.gp_cnt_cd
         WHERE a.pk_column1 = sc_ob_temp_audit.pk_column1
           AND a.pk_column2 = sc_ob_temp_audit.pk_column2
           AND ...
       )
```

I think that stands a chance of working; the WHERE clause on the sub-query should use `a` to identify the audit table in the sub-query and the full name to identify the audit table in the UPDATE statement.  But there's a chance I'm mis-thinking given the time of night.

Comment: He is also using `OUTER JOIN` without specifying if it's a `LEFT`, `RIGHT` or `FULL` outer join.

Comment: That would be an issue if the notation in general was supported; it isn't, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: I guesss only the `UPDATE (SELECT ...query-with-joins...) x SET x.export_flag ='Y'` syntax is supported, right?

Comment: @ypercube its suppose to be OUTER LEFT JOIN

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler if informix doesn't support Update with join then how could join the tables?.Anyway I have to convert this query to hibernate later on.